# Copying all files from one docker volume to another using wild card characters?

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux, ash

This works because it's copying `some_file`:

```
docker run --rm -v target-data:/target -v ~/source:/source alpine cp source/some_file target/
```

This does not (Using wildcard):

```
docker run --rm -v target-data:/target -v ~/source:/source alpine cp source/* target/
cp: can't stat 'source/*': No such file or directory
```

How do copy all the files in the `souce` volume to the `target` volume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is who expand that `*`:

```
docker run --rm -v target-data:/target -v ~/source:/source alpine sh -c 'cp -r source/* target/'
```

You need someone (`sh`) to expand the `*` before the program is launched (that is what the shell do before exec `cp`)

Comment: Brilliant - I also needed directories so I had to add `cp -r source/ ...`